Entity Framework Core: use connection string from appsettings.json
I'm trying to use appsettings.json to store the database connection string to use different strings for build configurations. But, I'm getting this exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: A named connection string was used, but the name 'ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection' was not found in the application's configuration.

Here is my appsettings.json:
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=adserver\\VALLOUREC;Database=eddb000;user id=devnepre;Password=nepre;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;TrustServerCertificate=True"
}

And here is how is my database context configuration:
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");

In program.cs, the settings are loaded like this:
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

And I use AddDbContext but that doesn't change anything.
I tried some solutions suggested in this topic, but these did not work.
I know I can put the connection string directly in the OnConfiguring function, but I don't want to do this because every time I scaffold the database, the code is changed and I need to revert this part.
Edit: when i Scaffold the database with this command:
Scaffold-DbContext Name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer - force
the OnConfiguring is aways replaced by this:
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection");


i'm trying to make it works with this implementation to avoid needs to change every time o run the command.

I’ve realized that the error was not coming from my main DbContext. The project has a second Database Context that inherits the first one.
I just needed to add this code for this second context and it now works:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ExampleDbContext>(options =>
options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

The inherited DbContext was not able to instantiate its parent until I implement the right constructor receiving the DbContextOptions<>.

You should be able to use IConfiguration interface with registered settings from defined sources (appsettings.json in your case).
So, during registration process, you just call:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ExampleDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


I tried, but don't worked.

As far as I know, ASP.NET uses the .NET generic host. When I did some research, I found that we can get configuration values or settings through the IConfiguration interface.
To do so, create a new constructor that asks for the IConfiguration type through parameters, assign the IConfiguration parameter to a field, and then use it as in the following code to get the data from your config file; in this example its appsettings.json:
public class ExampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    public ExampleDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        Console.WriteLine(_configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
}

To enable depency injection for our ExampleDbContext, we can use the following code in our builder:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//other services, middleware, etc.
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ExampleDbContext>();
var app = builder.Build();

Note: I tried the above code in ASP.NET’s minimal API's and it worked. I am not sure about the ASP.NET MVC version.

Just be sure you don't keep the Console.WriteLine in the production code. Connection strings could be sensitive, and should not be logged.

probably it will work, but when i run the Scaffold command the DatabaseContext will be regenereted changing the OnConfiguring implementarion. That is why i trying to use the  Name syntax.

can u try to use another name for the database connection string? like
"ConnectionStrings": {
"ExampleConnection": "blablablabla"
}

also im not sure but can u use name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection instead of the one with capital N ( Name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection)
